# How to hide the GLSL implementation detail on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

Implementing image processing algorithm using GLSL on Android is simple. But the detail of the algorithm is easy to be found in the decompiled Java files as strings or in resource files. I am wondering if there existing a method to hide the detail of the GLSL such as using compiled GLSL source or some other technologies.

BTW, I prefer using GLSurfaceView.

Thanks.

Comment: If someone is willing to decompile your Java source, they're probably going to be willing to decompile any pre-compiled GLSL source too. If they want your code, they're going to get it. If you encrypt it, they'll just snatch it out of memory when you decrypt it. And quite frankly, odds are good that nobody is going to care about a couple of image processing shaders from some random app.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this app is a famous app running for 3 years in Google Play. The new image processing algorithm has been researched for months, so the company want to reduce the risk against being copied quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Encryption is really your best bet. In that it's your *only* bet; anyone who's willing to decompile your Java application will probably know how to decompile your binary shaders too.

Then again, since OpenGL requires either binary shaders or text, that means that, at some point, the decrypted shader will exist in memory. Which means that a user will be able to snatch it. There's really no way around that, and the more famous your application, the bigger of a target it will be.

Just use a decent encryption algorithm on your shader file. If you want to make them work a bit harder for it, encrypt the binary shaders.

Encryption *can* help with the platform-specific nature of shaders though. In order to make sure your application actually *works* on all possible Android devices, you can't really rely on shipping binary shaders. You can ship some binary shaders for specific pieces of hardware, but there are *lots* of Android devices. You can only ship so many binary formats.

For the major ones, your binaries will load. And that's where encryption helps. You still need to ship your text shaders, but if you encrypt them, then the user won't be able to decrypt them without either reading through your encryption algorithm or pulling them decrypted out of memory. And they can't do the latter if your binary shaders fit the hardware, since then you won't have to load and decrypt your text shaders at all.

So you can make someone put forth quite a bit of effort. But you can't stop them.

Comment: For the company, it will be OK if the GLSL code cannot be read directly. So I decide to use binary shaders. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesZhao: As stated by both myself and Andon, you *cannot* rely on every platform to be able to read binary shaders. *Especially* since new platforms keep coming out. Encryption is more reliable.

Comment: Got it. Encryption is really a good choice for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at `glShaderBinary (...)`. After compiling a shader you can query its binary representation from OpenGL ES and re-use that binary (with some major limitations).

You have to throw out what you think you know about bytecode executables; Java has a single JVM instruction set, so the binaries are universally executable - HLSL shaders can be distributed in binary format as well because Direct3D bytecode is an intermediate format that drivers will translate into native instruction sets for the underlying GPU.

In OpenGL, there is no standard bytecode format. The binary shaders that you get from GL are very likely hardware and/or driver-version specific. It is unlikely that you will be able to distribute software that uses binary shaders as a result, the primary use of binary shaders in GL is to cache compiled shaders not to make sourceless distribution a possibility.